# I am using react native for development and currently facing problem with gif support in android standalone builds

Tags: android, react-native, expo, fresco

I have seen many answers in stack overflow and GitHub but seems none of them satisfy. Maybe I am doing something wrong. Please specify me:

In my android/app/build.gradle :

```
   implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.0.1' 
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-base-support:1.0.1'
```

And I am using react native version :
From my package.JSON

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "^27.0.1",
    "firebase": "^5.0.3",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "~0.55.2",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-google-signin": "^0.10.0",
    "react-native-indicators": "^0.13.0",
    "react-navigation": "^2.17.0"
```

Please specify me where am I wrong I also used version 1.3 of fresco in my app still it doesn't work.

UPDATE: ADDING IMAGE TAG-CODE

```
<Image
source = {require('../Assets/Images/empty_cart.gif')}
resizeMode = 'contain'
style = {{flex:0.5,width:Dimensions.get('window').width,alignSelf: "center"}}/>
```

Comment: post you <image> tag code

Comment: Did @AkshayKatariya